# Angular Toastr with Jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-toastr

I'm working on a Jhipster project with angular 6, and I'm trying to write a code that appears when a certain event happens. I followed this step by step in a different application (a test), and it worked, but when I tried to use it in my project with Jhipster, the notification does not appear .. Does anyone know the right way to do it with jhipster?

I started working in this area a short time ago, and that's why I have doubts with Jhipster.

**Jhipster version 0.5.4**, **ngx-toastr 10.0.2**,
**Angular version 6.2.4**

I followed this example:
https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-create-angular-toastr-notifications/

Comment: Well, it is a purely client side feature so I don't know what JHipster could be messing up aside from providing you with incompatible dependency versions. Just update everything!

Comment: Please edit your question to put correct JHipster version, it can't be 0.5.4. You can find it in package.json at generator-jhipster (not ng-jhipster). You can find it also in your project's README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When things don't appear it's usually because the css stylesheets are not included.

The tutorial you linked tells you to refer to `toastr.css` within `styles` section of `angular.json`. This does not work with JHipster because it's not fully compatible with Angular CLI.

Read your project's `README.md` to learn about how to manage dependencies and styles.

Also, JHipster provides also its own toaster `JhiAlertService` which is already used to display success or error of API calls using an interceptor. It could be enough for some users.